# How to remove the combo box arrow in an access query in a field that isn't a combo box? I don't know why it's even showing up

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

The field is a regular text box with a short text parameter. In all of my forms I never once turned it into a combo box. However, in the query with no special criterion, whenever I enter a record and this field, a combo box "arrow" shows up. There is nothing to choose from but if I change the record, it gives me the combo box error that the specified item is not in the list. How do I remove this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you build lookup field in table design or even just select Combobox or Listbox for DisplayControl on Lookup tab? Don't do either.

Comment: @June7 Yes, that was the issue. I get looking in query design and all of the forms and found nothing. I did find some weird parameter for the lookup field under table design. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Advise to never build Lookup fields with Lookup wizard in table design. Also don't manually set DisplayControl property on Lookup tab to combobox or listbox. Most likely your design does the latter without setting RowSource property.